# Standard Error of Trimmed Mean

Tags: bootstrap, standard-error

In the famous article by Efforn and Tibshirani "Bootstrap Methods for Standard Errors, Confidence Intervals, and Other Measures of Statistical Accuracy", the authors make the following claim in page 57:

"Here $\mathcal X$ is the real line, $n=15$, and the statistics $\hat\theta$ of interest is the $25%$ trimmed mean. If the true sampling distribution $F$ is $N(0,1)$, then the true
standard error is $\sigma(F) = 0.286$. The bootstrap estimate $\hat\sigma$ is nearly unbiased, averaging 0.287".

Would anybody know how they get to such results? I mean, how to calculate this standard error for the 25% trimmed mean? This is specially strange since it's not clear how we should exclude the top 25% and the bottom 25% of 15 samples, since this is not an integer number.